# Change colors of candles in candlestick chart

Tags: vb.net, colors, charts, candlestick-chart

No matter what I've tried I can not change these colors.

Points in the chart are added from DGV:

```
 For Count As Integer = 1 To rowC
            Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DGVH1.Item(0, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(2, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(3, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(1, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(4, Count).Value)
        Next
```

I can set color2 and border color for all candles and wicks with :

```
 With Chart1.Series(0)
   .BorderColor = Color.DimGray
   .Color = Color.DimGray
```

and the result looks like this : 
[image]

...but can not change color1 (white color in first picture), also when color2 is change with this :

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To rowC - 1 'row count
        If DGVH1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(1).Value < DGVH1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(4).Value Then
                           Chart1.Series(0).Points(i).Color = Color.Tomato
        End If
    Next
```

I get this (wick color is also changed and changing `<` to `>`, in code above, doesn't change color 1) :

[image]

That looks pretty terrible. If someone is willing to give me some directions on how to fix this...

Thanks

**EDIT 1 : Data source for candlestick chart**

```
    DGVH1.Rows.Clear()
            DGVH1.Columns.Clear()
            Dim Today0 As Date = Date.Today
            Dim Day0 As Integer = Today0.Day
            Dim Month0 As Integer = Today0.Month - 1
            Dim Year0 As Integer = Today0.Year
            Dim Year10 As Integer = Today0.Year - 10

            Dim MonthFormat As String = "MMM"
            Dim MonthDate As String = (Today0.ToString(MonthFormat))

            Dim myUri As New Uri("http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=" & "AAPL" & "&startdate=" & MonthDate & "+" & Day0 & "%2C+" & Year10 & "&enddate=" & MonthDate & "+" & Day0 & "%2C+" & Year0 & "&num=30&ei=Ge5HVOGtEOaZwQPewYCoBQ=csv&output=csv")
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(myUri), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

            Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(receiveStream)
            'Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\AAPL Balance SheetA.csv")
            TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {","}
            While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
                Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()

                If DGVH1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim i As Integer

                    For i = 0 To 5
                        DGVH1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
                    Next
                End If

                DGVH1.Rows.Add(Row1)
            End While

            receiveStream.Close()
            response.Close()

'code below converts everything to numbers...some random values are not numerical (strings) 

            For i As Integer = 1 To DGVH1.RowCount - 2
                DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value + 0
                DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value + 0
                DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value + 0
                DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value + 0
                    DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value + 0
next
```

**EDIT 2 : Candlestick chart code**

```
Dim rowC As Integer = 50 'DGVH1.RowCount - 2

    With TAChart1
        .Legends.Clear()
        .Series.Clear()
    End With
TAChart1.Series.Add("Open")
TAChart1.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick


Dim Max1 As Long = 0
For i As Integer = 1 To rowC
    If Max1 < DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Then
        Max1 = DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
    End If
Next

Dim Min1 As Long = Max1
For i As Integer = 1 To rowC
    If Min1 > DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value Then Min1 = DGVH1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
Next

Max1 = Max1 * 0.01 + Max1
Min1 = Min1 - Min1 * 0.01


For Count As Integer = 1 To rowC
    TAChart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DGVH1.Item(0, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(2, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(3, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(1, Count).Value, DGVH1.Item(4, Count).Value)
Next

TAChart1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(25, 25, 25)

With TAChart1.ChartAreas(0)
    .AxisY.Minimum = Min1
    .AxisY.Maximum = Max1
    .AxisY2.Minimum = Min1
    .AxisY2.Maximum = Max1
    .AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    .AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.FromArgb(45, 45, 45)
    .AxisY2.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0
    .AxisX.IsReversed = True
    .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(25, 25, 25)
    .AxisX.LineWidth = 0
    .AxisY.LineWidth = 0
    .AxisY2.LineWidth = 0
    .AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro
    .AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = New Font("Cambria", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
    .AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = False
    .AxisY2.LabelStyle.Enabled = False
    .AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
    .AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
    .AxisY2.MajorTickMark.Enabled = False
    .AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = False
    .AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = False
    .AxisY2.MinorTickMark.Enabled = False
    .AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 40
    .AxisX.Interval = 5
End With

With TAChart1.Series(0)
    .BorderColor = Color.DimGray
    ' .Color = Color.Tomato
End With

For i As Integer = 0 To rowC - 1
    If DGVH1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(1).Value > DGVH1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(4).Value Then
        TAChart1.Series(0).Points(i).BorderColor = Color.DimGray
        TAChart1.Series(0).Points(i).Color = Color.Green
        TAChart1.Series(0).Points(i).LabelForeColor = Color.Green
    End If
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To rowC - 1
    If DGVH1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(1).Value < DGVH1.Rows(i + 1).Cells(4).Value Then
        TAChart1.Series(0).Points(i).BorderColor = Color.DimGray
        TAChart1.Series(0).Points(i).Color = Color.Red
        TAChart1.Series(0).Points(i).LabelForeColor = Color.Red
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried .forecolor?

Comment: Where is forecolor and how to use it? As far as I know it's only available for LabelStyle, Title, Label. For series there is only Color, that changes color of these gray/red candles, white is unchangeable.

Comment: Are you using a windows form? Does it not have a forecolor property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chart.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, it doesn't have forecolor property, only color and yes I am using Winform. BTW, loop above in original post show that changing color of a candle works fine only for candles with open price (column 1) lower then close price (column 4), if loop is working, by changing < to > color should change for color 1, but it doesn't. Strange.

Comment: I can add data source code for DGV in original post if you want to try creating Candlestick chart by yourself.

Comment: Check your Pallette property. It sets the colors for your graph.

Comment: Changing palette did nothing for me, color1 candles are still white, color2 candles did change color when palette changed...
I would like to have control over candle colors, to make them have that standard look, green and red with dimgray border and wicks.

Comment: .BackSecondaryColor. Try that.

Comment: I can not believe it, how did I missed that! I've tried every combination, twice, with anything that contains color in the name and didn't find BackSecondaryColor property to have any effect on my chart. Thank you so much, this thing drove me nuts.